# I only get one snippet of those with duplicate JSON keys in my VS Code snippets file. What's going on?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have made some VS Code snippets to speed up my markdown editing but I'm having a problem where they are not visible after pressing ctrl+space. This problem only started appearing when I added snippets containing html-tags.

For example:

```json
"Markdown formula": {
        "prefix": "blue",
        "body": [
            "<mark style=\"background: #00ced1!important\">$1</mark>$0"
        ],
        "description": "Markdown blue colored highlight"
    },

    "Markdown formula": {
        "prefix": "red",
        "body": [
            "<mark style=\"background: #ffbaba!important\">$1</mark>$0"
        ],
        "description": "Markdown red colored highlight"
    },
```

only the red snippet will be accessible via ctrl+space. But if I remove the red snippet the blue will work, consequently only the last html-containing snippet in the markdown.json file will be shown in the snippet menu. All other snippets (not containing any html) are unaffected and still works as before. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: why do they have the same key: `"Markdown formula"`, that is illegal JSON

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can reproduce the behaviour you describe with the code you have shown. It's because you've created two JSON keys with the same name for your snippets. That's invalid JSON. VS Code even warns about it with problem indicators (you should see squiggly underlines under those duplicate keys). Give your keys unique names and then the problem should be solved. Ex. in your case, `Markdown formula 1` and `Markdown formula 2`.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you for pointing out such a simple mistake. I was more careful when naming my snippets previously but got a bit lazy with copy and paste :P